# How many ways are there to color faces of a 4-cube?, all being painted with different colors.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

For 3-D,
We have no. of symmetries, i.e. order of acting group = **orbit(x)*stab(x)**.
Which is clearly, $6\cdot 4 = 24$, as four rotations stabilize a face, and each face can move to all other places under simple rotations about axis.

There will be $6!$ ways of coloring, but there is a certain over count, so we divide by $24$. Hence we get $30$ different combinations.

The question is, will the orbit(x) be all face positions? , and what about stabilizer of a face.
Also, can we generalize this for $n$-dimensions.

Comment: Do we color vertices or faces?

Comment: We are coloring the faces of the cube

Comment: Your question is vague. You mean, of course, distinguishable colorings — when you use the symmetries of the cube to identify one coloring with another.

Comment: What's a color?  You can use this approach to get the symmetries but are we allowed to color from a 255 RGB palette as an example?

Comment: The sole purpose of color is identification of faces, don't take it literally, finding the symmetries is a part of the problem.